# React router always rendering '/' path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use the v4 react router, but the router always renders the initial path ('/').
I'm using

`react: ^16.2.0`

`react-dom: ^16.2.0`

`react-router-dom: ^4.2.2`

When I try to render /#/account, it renders Home instead of Account.

```html
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Account from "./components/Account/Account";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Home</div>)} />
        <Route path="/account" render={() => (<div>Account</div>)} />
      </div>
  </Router>,
  app
)
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the ways to get around this is to make use of `<Switch>` from react-router-dom, You can import it like :

```
import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then wrap your `<Route>` inside `<Switch>` i think its a good idea to put `"/"` in the last and give default component as well like :

```
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/account" render={() => (<div>Account</div>)} />
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Home</div>)} />
          <Route component={NoMatch}/>
        </Switch>
     </div>
  </Router>
```

You can read more about `<Switch>` [Here](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf)

Comment: I did try this approach, no luck.

Comment: have you wrapped `<Route>` in `<Switch>` ? any errors in console ?

Comment: so after wrapping it with <Switch> , initial `"/"` is rendering as well ?

Comment: Yes, no matter what I enter in the url, it always renders `"/"`

Comment: Yeah, its kinda strange. I did remove exact, still the same.

Comment: if you are using webpack then inside `webpack.config.js` add `historyApiFallback: true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160359/discussion-between-aaqib-and-deepak-bandi).

Comment: What was the problem @DeepakBandi?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Whether I type in a different url, use a link, etc. It always renders the '/' path. Even though the url is different. I'm not using redux.

Answer (score 2):

I know its bit late but was facing same issue and thought of sharing with everyone.

Fixed by adding "exact" parameter to Route

```
<Route path="/contact-us" exact component={component-name} />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour since "/home" will match both "/" and "home" ,therefore both components are seen, it can be solved by adding 'exact' parameter to your "/" Route attribute like this :

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
<Route path="/about" component={About}/>
<Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `<BrowserRouter>` is `<HashRouter>` which uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. window.location.hash) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Therefore in your example you would simply import the `HashRouter` instead

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I ran into this issue and i'm sure I won't be the last.

In my case, there was a component on one page with a link to the other.

For example, it might be a `<Button onClick={goToHomePage()} />Go Home</Button>`component on the account page. When the account page is rendered, `goToHomePage()` is called instantly, re-routing the user to the home page. It'll happen pretty quickly, and be a bit confusing. This will also happen with a correct router setup.

I hope this helps someone in the future!